# Following links to get RSS entry content with feedzirra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss, feedzirra

I have a Rails app (3.2.11, Ruby 1.9.3) and I'm trying to read the feed at `http://www2c.cdc.gov/podcasts/createrss.asp?t=r&c=66` using [feedzirra](https://github.com/pauldix/feedzirra).  Looking at the source XML of the feed, this is what entries looks like:

```
<item>
    <title>In the News - Novel (New) Coronavirus in the Arabian Peninsula and United Kingdom</title>
    <description>Novel (New) Coronavirus in the Arabian Peninsula and United Kingdom</description>
    <link>http://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/notices/in-the-news/coronavirus-arabian-peninsula-uk.htm</link>
    <guid isPermaLink="true">http://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/notices/in-the-news/coronavirus-arabian-peninsula-uk.htm</guid>
    <pubDate>Thu, 07 Mar 2013 05:00:00 EST</pubDate>
</item>
<item>
    <title>Outbreaks - Dengue in Madeira, Portugal</title>
    <description>Dengue in Madeira, Portugal</description>
    <link>http://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/notices/outbreak-notice/dengue-madeira-portugal.htm</link>
    <guid isPermaLink="true">http://wwwnc.cdc.gov/travel/notices/outbreak-notice/dengue-madeira-portugal.htm</guid>
    <pubDate>Wed, 20 Feb 2013 05:00:00 EST</pubDate>
</item>
```

As you can see, this feed doesn't seem to be exposing the entry contents, just a `link` to the underlying article.  My question is this, can I use `feedzirra` to access the content of the original article?  If not, any recommendations on good tools out there?  `wget`? `mechanize`? `httparty`?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know if it's possible with feedzirra, but from what I see with the XML, all you can get is the title and some more snippets like the description, pubication date..., I can however recommend a tool for this, you should check **[FeedsAPI](http://www.feedsapi.org)** , it has a nice simple to use RSS Feeds API and can do what you are tryng to achieve. i hope this could help.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to keep using `feedzirra` for this functionality, but in the meantime I'll definitely check out FeedsAPI.  Thanks for the suggestion!